# Access violation while creating custom objects with automatic storage and pushing back onto std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

The following snippet of code produces this Access violation:

> Unhandled exception at 0x006013dc in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation at location 0x00000000006013dc.

```
        std::vector<MyObject> v;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           MyObject obj(global_symbolDe->agentManager(), 5, global_symbolDe->agentManager().createNewUniqueId(), false);
           v.push_back(obj);
        }
```

Unfortunately, I do not have the source for MyObject, as I am developing a plugin for third-party software, using their API; but the debugger points to the end brace of the for loop, indicating that this is the next line in the thread of execution when it returns from the current function.  Clearly there's nothing particularly sophisticated going on here, but I'm having trouble determining the issue.  I believe the object itself, or my misuse of the object, is the culprit - as a sanity check I tried the same exact code using a different custom object, without any problems:

```
    std::vector<MyObject2> v2;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       MyObject2 obj2(global_symbolDe->agentManager(), 5, global_symbolDe->agentManager().createNewUniqueId(), false);
       v2.push_back(obj2);
    }
```

In debugging, I can Show Disassembly on the line where the exception occurs, though I'm not sure how useful this is to solving the problem:

```
000007FED17FAB43  mov  r11,qword ptr [rbx+98h]
```

Without dumping tons of code here, I'll mention that the function in which this code is called is a static member function.

Any ideas what might be causing the issue, or what I might look out for as a potential cause?

Comment: Perhaps `MyObject2` does not have correct copy/move semantics; or  `global_symbolDE->agentManager()` has a problem

Comment: If you are using a header defining `MyObject2` but a supplied binary of its implementation, then cans of worms start to be opened

Comment: From what you describe it is happening during destructor-time for that ``MyObject`` instance.  Probably as an after effect of bad copy - construction code. Since you do not use ``std::move()``, the instance inside the vector is being copy-constructed and you would not need worry about Move semantics here. What is always possible in case of using DLLs is that you are confronted with a clash of different runtime-libraries on your and the DLLs side. Just to make sure your input arguments are good, consider adding a few asserts.

Comment: The MyObject class is clearly the problem. It is either broken, or you are not using it the way it's meant to be used. If it's from a third party library, perhaps you should mention what it actually is. Maybe someone else is familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

MyObject has a raw pointer member, but no copy constructor defined; therefore the default copy constructor does a soft copy of the pointer into the new MyObject that is put into the vector. When obj goes out of scope after each iteration of the for loop, the pointer is deleted, leaving the fresh-copy-inside-of-the-vector's pointer to point to nothing! The third party should have defined a copy constructor to do a deep copy of the pointer, or else made a private copy constructor to restrict copying.